# There is a trouble to openning debugger window in windows 10 with jxbrowser 6.23 & 6.23.1

Tags: jxbrowser

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFR3B.png

Only one error：
08:22:50 FATAL: [0325/202250.082:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1018)] Lost UI shared context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can happen that the Chromium engine can lose UI shared context in some cases. Usually, Chromium will restore the context and continue rendering. In that case, something happened that prevented Chromium from restoring the context.

As a workaround, you can try using [accelerated lightweight rendering](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000104965-accelerated-lightweight-rendering). It is faster than the usual lightweight rendering and does not use GPU. As a downside, the WebGL functionality will be disabled.

Could you please try enabling the full Chromium logs, reproduce the issue and send them to me? You can enable Chromium logs with the following Chromium switches: `--enable-logging --v=1`. The output will be saved to the file *chrome_debug.log* in Chrome's user data directory. Also, JxBrowser logs could be helpful too. You can find how to enable JxBrowser logs using the following link: [Logging](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013125-logging)

In addition, the message you got, can be produced by the Chromium engine when the `--disable-gpu` or `--disable-gpu-compositiong` switch is passed to it.